# Concerns about Fing scanner

Tags: ip, network-scanners, cloud-computing

For years I have been using the Fing iOS app to scan my home network to check for unknown devices.  The iOS apps is nice and self contained, so I never worried much about its own security.

I recently downloaded the Windows Fing desktop application.  Worked great, has a easy interface, and provides better results than other scanners I have tried.

BUT ... The desktop app requires one to create a Fing account, and the results of the scan are uploaded to Fing cloud.  So basically now my external IP, all my internal IPs, and all my device's MACs are on the cloud.  At first blush this seems like a huge security concern.

Has anyone encountered any security issues with the Fing service?

Comment: This is not the place for product reviews or product comparison or to evaluate how a specific service __currently__ behaves. It is unknown to us what Fing currently does with these data and what it might do with these data in the future. In general: data which are collected can be used and misused and service providers might change their terms if this is needed for a new business model. Data are considered worth a lot today.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich.  Thank you for your feedback.  I can delete the question if not appropriate.